# PHP on IIS - handle everything with index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, iis, url-rewriting

I am having a problem with redirects on IIS 10 with PHP site.

When using a Apache:
.htaccess file in root

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www/$1 [L]
```

In www folder I have this .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !\.(pdf|js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|rar|zip|tar\.gz|map)$ index.php [L]
```

I want to replicate that behaviour using IIS 10, but I options I have tried was incorrect.

Web.config in root:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="wwwRedirect" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="www/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

In www folder I have this web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <remove name="wwwRedirect" />
            <rule name="indexRedirect" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="\.(pdf|js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|rar|zip|tar\.gz|map)$" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Now I am getting the HTTP 404.0 – Not Found when accessing the web.

When I open the web, I am redirec to www folder and there to index.php as a default file. The index call the url sign/in, so I am on localhost/sign/in, but IIS is searching for file \www\sign\in

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules Enable tracing and see what's wrong.